# How can I allow my script to allow any parameter?

Tags: powershell, command-line-interface

I'm trying to figure out how I can get my PowerShell script to allow arbitrary parameters without me having to specify everything I could potentially expect using `param`.

Searching around I see I can use `$args` and `$myinvocation.mycommand.unboundarguments`.

What I would like to do is -

```
.\myscript.ps1 -prop1 "foo" -prop2 "bar"
```

The purpose of this is that I plan on using the property to value key pairs for updating my config files.

Is such thing possible?

Comment: Accept a hash table instead?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$Args` will capture all inputs which have not been explicitly defined as parameters.

See [about_Automatic_Variables](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847768.aspx) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

Illustration of `$Args` from @Jon-Tirjan's answer,
showing how it skips the parameters which have been declared.

```
# myscript.ps1

param (
    [string] $param1,
    [string] $param2
)

Write-Host "param1 = $param1"
Write-Host "param2 = $param2"

$n = 0
foreach ($arg in $args) {
    write-host "$n $arg"
    $n += 1
}
```

`.\myscript.ps1 -param2 'p2' -foo -bar bim -param1 'p1' -zip zap`

```
param1 = p1
param2 = p2
0 -foo
1 -bar
2 bim
3 -zip
4 zap
```